# Can javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis be used without a Chart?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am working on a pannable and zoomable pane, and I would like to add a ruler at the top and on the left side of the pane, so that I know the position of features on the pane. I didn't find any 'ruler' class, but the NumberAxis seems to be what I need. I have created the following code:

```java
public HBox addHorizontalRuler() {
        HBox hr = new HBox();
        NumberAxis numberAxis = new NumberAxis();
        numberAxis.setLowerBound(0);
        numberAxis.setUpperBound(100.0);
        numberAxis.setTickUnit(1.0);
        numberAxis.setMinHeight(10);
        hr.getChildren().add(numberAxis);
        return hr;
    }
```

and then I am addding the HBox to the pane. Unfortunately, I can't make it appear on my scene. Can NumberAxis be used without any corresponding Chart object?

Comment: yeah, sure - please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok, figured this out already. Thanks.